# Authorization in dropwizard

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I want to make an small application using dropwizard in 0.8.0-rc3-SNAPSHOT. In that I want if any user will call my api user should pass an authtoken in the header part.What I have done till now is---

```
@Override
public void run(HelloWorldConfigurationhelloWorldConfiguration,Environment environment) throws Exception{
environment.jersey().register(new ViewResource());      
environment.servlets().addFilter("MyCustomRequestFilter", new MyCustomRequestFilter())
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST),false, "/*");
}

public class MyCustomRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
@Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    System.out.print("test");
    if ( request.getQueryParameters().containsKey("validateMeParam") ) {
              /* validation logic */
    }
    // finished validation
    return request;
}
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.It's not working.

Comment: What goes wrong? Does the compiler give you an error?

Comment: No errors,but not working on runtime.

Comment: I suggest using authenticators (https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/auth.html) instead of request filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ContainerRequestFilter` is not a Servlet `Filter`, which is what you are assuming by doing `environment.servlets().addFilter`. This should be added to the Jersey configuration.

```
environment.jersey().register(MyCustomRequestFilter.class);
```

And don't forget the `@Provider` annotation on the filter class.

- See more about filters in [**Jersey Filters**](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html#jersey-filters) in the Dropwizard documentation.

---

**UPDATE**

I see another serious problem. You say you're using Dropwizard 0.8.0, which uses Jersey 2. In which case, the `ContainerRequestFilter` you posted should not even exist. In Jersey 1, the parameter to the `filter` method, is `ContainerRequest`, while the argument in Jersey 2 is `ContainerRequestContext`. Please show you dependencies, and verify that the class you have above is the actual class

Comment: Did you look at the link? The example uses a `DynamicFeature` to map certain method, with the use of an annotation, but if you don't need that (i.e. you want all requests to go through the filter), then you don't need to implement the `DynamicFeature`, just register the filter as seen above. Other than just you just need to make sure you're using the right `ContainerRequestFilter`. The one you have in your post seems to be the Jersey 1 interfaces, which begins with `com.sun`. The filter you need for Jersey 2 should begin with `javax.ws.rs`.

Comment: Why is the `@Provider` annotation important? I don’t have that in my code and it seems to be working just fine (Dropwizard 1.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for this type of samples

https://github.com/stevenalexander/dropwizard-security

/* An example security provider that will look at each request when received by an endpoint using the auth attribute */

```
public class ExampleSecurityProvider<T> implements InjectableProvider<Auth, Parameter> {

public final static String CUSTOM_HEADER = "custom-security-token";

private final Authenticator<ExampleCredentials, T> authenticator;

public ExampleSecurityProvider(Authenticator<ExampleCredentials, T> authenticator) {
    this.authenticator = authenticator;
}

private static class ExampleSecurityInjectable<T> extends AbstractHttpContextInjectable<T> {

    private final Authenticator<ExampleCredentials, T> authenticator;
    private final boolean required;

    private ExampleSecurityInjectable(Authenticator<ExampleCredentials, T> authenticator, boolean required) {
        this.authenticator = authenticator;
        this.required = required;
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue(HttpContext c) {
        // This is where the credentials are extracted from the request
        final String header = c.getRequest().getHeaderValue(CUSTOM_HEADER);

        try {
            if (header != null) {
                final Optional<T> result = authenticator.authenticate(new ExampleCredentials(header));
                if (result.isPresent()) {
                    return result.get();
                }
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        if (required) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is jersey 1.x solution. Dropwizard 0.8 has jersey 2.x which has a different approach to it. https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/auth.html But I agree that the authenticators should be used instead of request filters.